# Error using Salesforce SOAP API with PHP - "An internal error has occurred"

Tags: php, cakephp, soap, salesforce

Trying to use the Salesforce SOAP API with PHP.  I am getting the following error on attempting to use any of the SForceEnterpriseClient methods.

```
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Stack Trace

#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('retrieve', Array)
#1 /path/to/public_html/site/app/Lib/Salesforce/SforceBaseClient.php(835): SoapClient->retrieve(Object(stdClass))
#2 /path/to/public_html/site/app/Model/MyModel.php(28): SforceBaseClient->retrieve('Id, Name', 'Contact', Array)
```

I do not know how to debug this problem, it is not a very descriptive error.  Help would be much appreciated!

I'm using CakePHP 2, in case that's relevant.

Edit - more detail:

```
SForceEnterpriseClient->login(stuff)
```

is working fine.  No problems there.  The error is when I try to use upsert or retrieve (ie actually do anything once I'm logged in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable tracing in the soap client and call the debug methods to get more info

```
$client = new SoapClient(array('trace' => true, 'exception' => false));

$client->retrieve('stuff');

var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
var_dump($client->__getLastResponseHeaders());
```

Comment: An exception was being thrown - following this debugging, wrapping the call in try { etc...} catch { ... } gave me more useful errors.  Just didn't realise exceptions gave that generic error!